# Why does the predefined `const` function behave differently than the equivalent lambda function in certain contexts?

Tags: haskell, lambda, sharing

While doing some experiments with sharing, I discovered that the predefined `const` function behaves differently in some contexts.

```hs
f :: (() -> Int) -> Int
f g = g () + g ()

x1 = f (const   (trace "x1" 42))
x2 = f (\_ ->   (trace "x2" 42))
x3 = f (myconst (trace "x3" 42))

myconst :: a -> b -> a
myconst x _ =  x
```

When [this example](https://gist.github.com/nbun/2a47b3ceecafd7a312d51d8a92aeba86) is compiled without optimizations, evaluating `x1` triggers the evaluation of `trace` only once, while it is evaluated twice for `x2` and `x3`. This is plausible for `x2` due to the lambda function.

```hs
x1
x2
x2
x3
x3
252
```

The [definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#const) of `const` suggests, however, that it is an ordinary function definition without any compiler annotations that could explain the difference. The function `myconst` should therefore behave the same, which it does not. How can this behavior be explained and is there a way to influence the compiler in this regard?

Comment: Interesting. FWIW, in _interpreted_ mode, `x3` is printed only once.

Comment: Try putting `myconst` in a library, compiling the library with optimizations, then rerunning your examples.

Comment: It's also printed only once if you put `{-# NOINLINE f #-} {-# NOINLINE myconst #-}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `myconst` is compiled into a separate module (even if the separate module is compiled with `-O0`), then the output is:

```
x1
x2
x2
x3
252
```

The difference is that -- in `-O0` code -- calling `myconst` in a separate module generates the code:

```
let x' = myconst (trace "x3" 42) in x' + x'
```

but calling `myconst` in the same module inlines it like so:

```
trace "x4" 42 + trace "x4" 42
```

Compiling with `-O2` completely changes the code -- everything is inlined and the traces are lifted to the top of the expression, so they only execute once each.

You can clearly influence the compiler in this regard, for example by putting `myconst` in a separate module or not, or -- as pointed out by @leftroundabout -- by adding various inlining pragmas.

I don't think you can *reliably* influence the compiler in this regard, and I'm not sure how much you can learn about real-world GHC code by studying unoptimized compilation output.  I think the above example clearly demonstrates that code generated with `-O0` will behave in completely arbitrary and contradictory ways based on minor aspects of the compilation that you wouldn't expect to matter.